# Question about time constant of Voltage Multiplier

Tags: ac, diodes, switch-mode-power-supply

[image: Voltage Doubler Circuit]

---

*Time Constant is Large Compared to Time Period* i.e. $$R_LC_{1,2}>>T=1/f$$

---

can someone please explain, whats the meaning of this line and how is this affecting the circuit behavior. I am looking for answer in little bit simple language. Thanks

Comment: A hint: \$X >> Y\$ means that \$X\$ is much bigger than \$Y\$

Comment: The rectified voltage decays very slowly from its peak value compared with the periodic time of the ac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a pair of half-wave rectifier DC power supplies connected back to back to double the output voltage.

[image]

*Figure 1. A simple half-wave rectifier with DC smoothing capacitor. Source: [Electronics Tutorials](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_5.html).*

- Without the capacitor the output voltage from this circuit would just be the positive half of the sine-wave.
- By adding a capacitor we can charge it up when the AC voltage > capacitor voltage.
- The capacitor then acts as a reservoir during the dips in the AC and supplies the load.
- The slope of the discharge of the capacitor will be inversely proportional to the \$ RC \$: the higher the resistance of the load, the slower the discharge; the higher the value of the capacitor, the slower the discharge.
- The variation between the peak voltage and the lowest dip between half-cycles is known as "ripple".

All that \$R_LC_{1,2}>>T=1/f\$ is telling you is to make sure you have enough capacitance in there to keep the ripple small for the mains frequency you are on.

Example:

- 100 Ω load.
- f = 50 Hz so T = 20 ms.

Rearranging the formula to find C: \$C_{1,2}>> \frac {T}{R_L} = \frac {20m}{100} = 0.2 \ \mathrm {mF} \$

So if we consider that a factor of ten will satisfy the '>>' requirement we would choose 2 mF or 2000 µF capacitors.

---

Note that the calculation in the original circuit is complicated by the fact that the load resistance is connected across *both* supplies. For this reason when calculating the RC values we should consider half the load resistor for the R value. (The mid-point of the resistor is approximately at midpoint of the voltages.)

Comment: @fpsshubham: See the note I added to the end. Thank you for accepting my answer.